# Can we add playing recommendations to the off-topic list in the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, topics, help-center

Can we clarify the FAQ and add playing recommendations to the off-topic list in it? Here is what it should be like (or something similar):

> **...**
>
> and it is not about...
>
> - identifying a song, genre, instrument, etc.
> - shopping or buying/selling recommendations
> - audio production techniques and equipment
> - listening/**playing** recommendations
> - requesting a list of resources
> - legal issues
>
> ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!
>
> **...**

Comment: Would asking for more broad recommendations (aka a whole entire genre/sub-genre) be acceptable?

Comment: Do you have an example question?

Comment: I want to learn how to play [technique], what genre of music should I look to for practice?

Comment: It might be better phrased as "What genres of music commonly employ [technique]?"

Comment: Very true. I guess you're right.

Comment: @segiddins And the other option is "How can I learn [technique]?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've changed it to

> listening recommendations or recommendations of pieces to play

since I found "playing recommendations" a little unclear.  What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

As @segiddings noted in a comment, many of these questions can be edited from

> What music can I play to learn [technique]?

to just

> How can I learn [technique]?

and be salvaged.